Confusing output when saving tag edit
Let's have a look at this:

I'm rather confused, because:

If i don't have tag edit privileges, why can I start editing the tag at all?
If the edit is placed in a queue, why does it say "An error occurred submitting the post"?

In my logic, I can either sub mit, or I cannot.
Likewise I can either start editing, or I can not.
Is it a programming error, or the result of a "mid-air collision" (When I was ignorant and just pressed the "Save Edits" button again at some later time, it succeeded)?

I'm not quite clear; was this a temporary error and you submitted the edit successfully later, or did it continue to fail?

I just cleared myself up -- there is a pending edit from you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/470514

Please read the guidance on creating tag wikis. Tag wikis should not be definitions of the word used in the tag, especially not for common words like hyphenation. They should instead explain how the tag should be used on the site, what kinds of questions should have the tag.

OK, I didn't do many tag wiki edits before, actually, but I think it's better to have some explanation compared to having none (such tags do exist). And my guess was when I explained what I mean with hyphenation, it's obvious to tag questions that are about hyphenation (I'd consider a description like "use for questions about hyphenation." rather useless, unless you define what you mean by hyphenation). Well, in the hyphenation case it might be rather obvious, but there are many tags where this is not the case.

Think of how the tag is used on the site. For example, it would be applicable to questions about cutting human language text correctly on syllables using the syllabication rules of different languages. It would not be applicable to questions asking about options beginning with a -. That's the kind of thing tag wikis should explain, not what hyphenation means, but how the tag should and should not be used on the site.

Fair point, but if you read my definition, it's more like covering both cases. I mean: Tags should not be over-specific (like (the non-existing) division-by-zero-in-c (division-by-zero, combined with c-language should be good enough).

This looks like a minor, temporary bug. There was apparently an issue submitting your edit, but it did actually go through.
Such temporary glitches happen with most software. I wouldn't worry about it unless it happens regularly.

Well, glitches are OK, but the error message could be better.

@U.Windl I don't really see how. That's the classic error message for "whoops, one of various things that very rarely go wrong went wrong here". Unless this is a regular occurrence, it just isn't worth writing code for every possible edge case and providing a specific error message for each. The message tells you that an error occurred while submitting the post. As you correctly point out in your question, you clearly have the right to submit else you wouldn't have had access to the form in the first place, it's just that the submission failed for some reason.

Naturally, not having the details that caused the original error message, I cannot really suggest a better one (as it depends on the reason). Here it seems OK to just re-try, but when some larger money transfer in online-banking seemed to "be frozen", I would not simply re-try ;-)
